# copying bank account information into excel / google sheets, lists all info in 1 column instead of grid formation

Tags: microsoft-excel, google-spreadsheets

My bank account informaiton on the website is in a grid formation (ie: name of transaction, value, total in bank)

When I copy and past this information into google sheets or excel, it lists all this information into a single column instead of that grid formation.

How do I prevent this from happening?

Comment: I don't think Google Docs allow retaining source formatting, Excel does that though

Answer (score 1):

First check to see if your bank website has a feature to export to Excel or CSV format. This would be ideal, and many bank websites do have this feature. If not, you can use a browser extension to copy the table properly:

- Chrome: [Table Capture](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/table-capture/iebpjdmgckacbodjpijphcplhebcmeop?hl=en)
- Firefox: [Dafizilla Table2Clipboard](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/dafizilla-table2clipboard/)